# How to trim a text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my screenshot:

[image: Here is my screenshot:]

and this is my following code :

```
<div style="background:green; width:100px; height:27px;">
This is text to be written here
</div>
```

My question, how to trim my text if it goes out of the div? I want my text is being trimmed like the second box. Please tell me how to do it.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/jpobTRIYUCfukv95Dq1q?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add this to your style.

`text-overflow: ellipsis; overflow: hidden;   white-space: nowrap;`

[image]

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/aligajani/a95Lz4ub/)

Answer (score 4):

Use the `overflow` and `text-overflow` css rule

```css
div {
  overflow: hidden
  text-overflow: hidden
}
```

```html
<div style="background:green; width:100px; height:27px;">
This is text to be written here
</div>
```

`text-overflow` will only work when the container's overflow property has the value hidden, scroll or auto and white-space: nowrap as described in the link below

[This site](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/) talks about the topic well if you'd like to learn more

Answer (score 3):

Set the style `text-overflow, white-space, overflow` property:

```html
<div style="background: green;height: 27px;overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis; white-space: nowrap; width: 100px;">
This is text to be written here
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` property with `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;`.

So, your code will look like this

```
<div style="background:green; width:100px; height:27px;text-overflow: ellipsis;white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">
This is text to be written here
</div>
```

[Here](http://quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/textoverflow.html) is a good explanation of what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Set the following style properties:

- `text-overflow:ellipsis`
- `white-space:nowrap`
- `overflow:hidden`

```html
<div style="background:green; width:100px; height:27px; text-overflow:ellipsis; white-space:nowrap; overflow:hidden;">
This is text to be written here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to your code:

```css
div{
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div style="background:green; width:100px; height:27px;">
This is text to be written here
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to trim the text using css or jquery

> jquery

```
<div id="text">
This is text to be written here
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  var text =$('#text').html();
  if(text.length>20){
   $('#text').html(text.substr(0,20)+'...') ;
  }
 });
```

> Css

```
<div id="css">
This is text to be written here
</div>

 #css {
  text-overflow: ellipsis ;
  background:green; 
  width:100px; 
  height:27px;
  display:inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Thanks